# Getting an error when trying to use private PDO object

Tags: php, oop, pdo

So i'm setting up a class that allows me to query the database within it using simple functions, however im getting the following error whenever I try to use the database:
`Using $this when not in object context`

My code:

```
class Test {
    // Database variables
    private $DB, $DBconnectString = '';

    // Construct method (works perfectly)
    function __construct(){
        try {
            $this->DB = new PDO($this->DBconnectString, static::DATABASE_USERNAME, static::DATABASE_PASSWORD);
            $this->DB -> exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
            $this->DB -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch(PDOexception $error) {
            error_log($error);
            die('Could not connect to the database');
        }
    }

    // I get an error whenever I try to query from the database.
    public static function test() {
        $query = $this->DB->prepare('SELECT * FROM `testable`');
        $query -> execute($data);
    }
}

// I call this function like this:
$Test= new Test();
$Test->test();
```

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: @hjpotter92 

$Test= new Test();
$Test->test();

Comment: @hjpotter92 They're automatically public if you don't define them as private or protected.

Comment: @Paradoxis What do you get when you `var_dump($this->DB);`?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I get the exact same error

Comment: @Paradoxis comment out $Test->test(); and see if the error still occurs so you can localize if it occurs in the constructor on in the test function.

Comment: @Makville I tried that, the error is originating from the test function.

Comment: @Paradoxis Did you omit the definition of `$data` for testing purposes? `$query->execute($data);`

Comment: @silkfire yes, the error is pointing at the line above.

Comment: Could your problem be related to the dozens of Google results that come up for that error message? https://www.google.de/search?q=PDO+"Using+%24this+when+not+in+object+context"

Comment: @Paradoxis: unrelated: but you aught to undelete that question with you just closed. I was typing up an answer because there are some other issues with your code well worth noting

Comment: Cannot reproduce this error. Could you create the shortest code necessary to reproduce issue?

Comment: @sectus I already found a way to fix it, I accidentally made one of my database variables that needed to be used static which caused it. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the `public static`, removing the `static` keyword fixed the code.